# confusing to find the integral. can suggest any method

Tags: calculus, integration

I know 
$$\int \frac{1}{x \log x} \, dx = \log(\log x) + C.$$ 
Is there any way to find the integral of 
$$\int \frac{1}{x \log(x+1)} \, dx.$$

Comment: There is no elementary antiderivative for $\dfrac{1}{x\log(x+1)}$.

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{x \log (x+1)} \, dx+C=\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^t (1+x)^{-t} \,
   _2F_1\left(t,t;1+t;-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{t} \, dt+C$ where `2F1` hypergometric function.